# React UI and PHP Rest API on AWS

Tags: php, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have the following setup for my website:

- UI - using React
- Backend REST API - using PHP

For authentication, I used AWS Amplify.  So I host the UI in Amplify console and setup the backend environment for the authentication.  In my UI, I have 2 pages:

- Home page - "/"
- Main page - "/main"

I wrapped the Main component in `withAuthenticator` from `@aws-amplify/ui-react`.  With this, when i go to "/main" and the user has not signed in, it will show the default SignIn/SignUp from amplify.

My questions are these:

1. There are some parts on the Main page where I need to hide for non-admin users, say an "Admin" button that is only available for admin users.  In Amplify Studio, there is "User Management" where you can create users.  As I understand, it uses AWS Cognito for the user pool.  But how should I configure a user to be an admin?
2. Since I am wrapping the UI's main page inside Amplify's authenticator, I can be sure that only authenticated users can access that page and send requests to the backend.  To make sure that I am only showing buttons that are for admin users, I am thinking of creating an endpoint called "/profile" that will be called once my Main component loads and it will return an attribute telling me if the user is an admin or not.  But how do I check if the user is an admin from inside PHP API?
3. The logged in user can update his profile like update his name, location, etc. For this, I will create a user_profile table in MySQL to contain these other user attributes.  When the user first signup and confirm using Amplify and he's routed to the "/main" page, I'll call the "/profile" endpoint and check first if the user exists in the user_profile table?  If not, I'll add that user so he can update his profile later?  Is this the right approach?
4. Since my PHP REST APIs can be called even through say Postman, I also need to check in the backend if the request has the amplify token and check with Cognito if this is a valid token.  So for all endpoints, I need to check if the token is valid.  Is that correct approach and how to do that?
5. I am thinking of deploying my PHP REST API on an EC2 instance.  I believe since they are all inside the AWS environment, I won't be having issues calling the endpoints from my UI. Is this the right approach?
6. The same of my MySQL db, I'll deploy to AWS RDS.  I hope this is correct.

I hope for your kind guidance on my doubts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So they are a lot of questions for 1 post. It would be better to ask each question in a different post as right now more than technical issue it looks like opinionated architectural discussion.

- Reach application can be build and exported into static website. Then all the integrations can be managed by CSR (Client Side Requests). This is a cost efficient and performant way to host react websites. You can host the site on S3+Cloudfront and don't have to manage any servers
- For your APIs use API Gateway + AWS Lambda (Your PHP code). You can use token based authentication for your APIs and yes have to check every request if the token is valid.
- To check if a user is admin or any other role you can create "groups" in AWS Cognito. Reference to create groups is below
- Now what type of user can perform what type of role in your application has to be implemented in your application itself. Cognito can't help you with that part

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html